# Color issues in making positive bar chart values red and negative values blue? MATLAB

Tags: matlab, bar-chart

So I currently do have a bar chart that is showing positive values in red and negative in blue but my problem is when the bar chart shows ALL negative values or all positive values the coloring is all messed up. Below is what my code is:

```
dd = Data;
s = sign(dd);
barr = bar(dd); 
set(get(barr,'children'),'cdata',s);
```

I have also tried in SET 'FaceVertexCData'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just make two bar graphs in one plot

```
x = 1:length(s);

bar( x(s>0), dd(s>0), 'b');
hold on;
bar( x(s<0), dd(s<0), 'r');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define some color limits with

```
set(gca, 'CLim', [-1 1]);
```

Without it, when all signs are positive or negative (e.g. `s = [1 1 1 1]`), bars are plotted in green, which correspond to the mean value of the colormap. Setting the color limits to [-1 1] forces matlab to use the the extreme values of the colormap. You can also change the colors by setting `CLim` to [-10 10] for example.